# Use external library in WSO2 custom elements

Tags: java, wso2, apache-poi, wso2-esb

I'm currently some custom mediator and message builder for wso2 esb. for one of my project I need to use apache poi library.
wso2 esb already use this library, but an old version of it. Because of some issues I would need to use the latest version (3.15) But when I put it in component/lib folder it seems to be ignored and the version of the esb (in plugin folder) is used.
So my question is how to use external libraries that are already setup in the esb but in a different version?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use OSGi imports here. Here's what you have to do.

1) Make an OSGi jar from POI jar if it's not OSGi already. Make sure it exports its packages with a proper version. (i.e. 3.15 in your case).

2) Make your jar an OSGi bundle too. Then you can import the required version of POI bundle in your bundle.

3) Drop both OSGi jars to components/dropins (not lib).

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm not an OSGi expert but I'll try it.